# PDF reader with possiblity to read file with a different font

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer

Is there a PDF reader with possibility to change font from one font to another (just for easier reading). It don't need to modify the PDF file's original font, just changed while reading.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Don't forget that the text that you see on the page in a pdf can be any or all of: text _with a font and layout_, strokes on a background used to draw the same text __or__ an actual image of the text - depending on how the pdf was generated. In the first case a viewer can change the font but not in the later cases.

Comment: Yeah, I am award about all those case, this is just for simple text PDF file. What viewer can do that?

Comment: You might look at the Accessibility settings of Acrobat/Reader.

Answer (score 2):

A Foxit license or Adobe subscription would allow you to OCR (optical character recognition) the PDF and then edit it. The procedure of getting to editable text would be different per program but relatively simple if you searched "Edit text PDF Adobe/Foxit."

Foxit gives a free 14 day trial and after cost around $150 per license. Adobe Reader has a 7 day free trial and cost $13-$15 dollars per month.

Another option would be to try this http://www.onlineocr.net/. Downside is you need to create an account with them to convert multiple page PDFs.

Comment: Thanks, You're right, search "Edit text PDF Adobe/Foxit." Would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need OCR except when the pdf is an image pdf. If you just want to change the fonts, there is a program from Softmaker called Flexipdf that lets you just change the font. The program unfortunately is only available for Linux and Windows: http://www.softmaker.com/en/.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Online OCR](https://onlineocr.org) with it.

There is no need to create an account here to convert multi-page PDFs ;)